# Why I can not update my programs

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Every time I try to run the built-in software updater it tells me that it needs an additional 11.8 mb on "/boot" and to empty my trash, clean my system with sudo apt-get clean.

I've tried both methods and even ran bleachbit but it still says the same.

Comment: duplicate, but solution is great!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've a lot unused kernels,so you can delete unwanted kernel images and headers.

To list all installed kernels, run

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
```

One command to show all kernels and headers that can be removed, excluding the current running kernel:

```
kernelver=$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve $kernelver
```

I recommend test a newer kernel before removing older.
So, after upgrading kernels and rebooting to test it, you can remove all other kernels with:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

Comment: This answer is great. I had same issue and used it twice already as a resolution.